# apple's bug on -ObjC linker flag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker

I used to use static library these days and met lots of problems. I found an document and which puzzled me.
The [links](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html) tells the apple's -ObjC linker's bug for 64-bit and iPhone OS applications, and this line "For 64-bit and iPhone OS applications, there is a linker bug that prevents -ObjC from loading objects files from static libraries that contain only categories and no classes" really make me confused.
My question is what is "the static libraries that contain only categories and no classes"?

I write a category which I think it fit the condition but I works well without -all_load linker flag.
Here is my category.

```
@interface NSString (Len)

- (NSUInteger)len ;

@end

@implementation NSString (Len)

- (NSUInteger)len
{
    return [self length] ;
}

@end
```

Thank you for answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very old bug (as I remember in Xcode 3.4+) and already fixed many releases ago.

Comment: Is there some reference about that fixed bug ? You mean when I try to use static library with XCode 5.0, I just need to add -ObjC to Other Linker Flags?

Comment: I don't know about any references about this, but in our iOS applications we have couple of object files with only category methods. -ObjC flag only used.